# Checking an R-devel-linux error for my CRAN package using my MacBookPro

Tags: r, linux, virtual-machine, cran

I have a CRAN package that has inputenc errors when creating vignette PDF outputs in a strict Latin1 locale. The check results have errors for flavor
`r-devel-linux-x86_64-debian-clang`, which uses `LANG=en_US.iso885915`. I believe I may have fixed the problem (it was a warning on my Mac). However, I feel I should check the problem on Linux as well before submitting bug fixes to CRAN. It was suggested to me that to check that my package fixes the error on `LANG=en_US.iso885915`, that I should run the following command on Linux:

```
LANG=en_US.iso88591 R CMD check
```

I do not have access to Linux and will not for the reasonably foreseeable future. I am trying to figure out how to run this command on my macOS Catalina (version 10.15.3). With little experience running Linux on Mac, I have been doing searches online, with an example forum [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/aqxfvw/best_way_to_run_linux_on_macbook_pro/). There are some negatives discussed there, including the lack of necessity of running Linux on Mac (usually), installation of Linux restraints on latest MacBooks, and virtual machines not truly representing what Linux can do.

I decided it may be helpful for me to ask here on SO. I do not have too much storage left on my Mac and I would likely delete any Linux installations quickly since I will likely not need them outside of this one issue. I also do not have much experience installing virtual machines and Linux. I also hope to avoid any other risks I may not even be aware of to my computer.

**What is the best way (convenient, low risk, quick, low storage requirements) you may know for someone in my position to check this recommended command (`LANG=en_US.iso88591 R CMD check`) with access to simply my MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)?** Thank you for sharing suggestions!

Comment: Can't you boot into Ubuntu using a live cd? Not sure if/how you'd install R from there but might be worth a try if there are no alternatives.

Comment: @dario. Thanks for the advice. My MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015) does not appear to have a CD slot. I will look into it though.

Comment: ;) sorry, i was unclear, I should have said 'live bootable storage device'. Nobody has cd drives anymore in their notebooks ;) We use 'Ubuntu live USB sticks' nowadays...

Comment: Thanks @dario. And thanks for clearing up terminology. It seems I would [need access to an Ubuntu system](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/) to create such a storage device. I will keep it in mind, but probably cannot have access to Ubuntu system at this time.

Comment: You don't need access to a linux system to do this. Just download ubuntu installer, and when booting there should be an option to boot directly from the storage device